# Is this statement correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Define $N=\left\{\dfrac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}^+\right\}$, so $N\subset\mathbb{Q}$. We can also add to this $N\subset[0,1]$ or $N\subseteq(0,1]$ or $N\subset(0,1]$. Is saying $N\subseteq[0,1]$ also correct, even though $0$ is obviously not a member of $N$?

Comment: If the first statement is correct, then the other _must_ be correct.

Comment: You can't *let* $N$ be a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ and then *define* what it is. Instead you should define what $N$ is and then point out that it is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese; i've edited the Q - is that any better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $N \subset [0,1]$, whereby $N \subseteq [0,1]$ (remember that $\subset$ is a stronger condition than $\subseteq$). You can see this because the smallest element of $\mathbb{N}^+$ is $1$, and $1/1 = 1$, so the upper bound on $N$ is $1$, and the lower bound is $0$ (though no element of $N$ is $0$, as you can reason -- there is no fraction $1/n =0$.).

Note that $N \neq [0,1]$ because $N$ does not include any of the irrationals in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: does that mean $N\subseteq[0,1]$ is wrong?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry No, it's perfectly right. $\subseteq$ means "Subset or Equal", and $N$ is a subset of $[0,1]$, so $N \subseteq [0,1]$.

Comment: I quickly point out that the symbol "$\subset$" is used variously. Sometimes it means simply "is a subset of", and sometimes it means "is a strict subset of". When used along with "$\subseteq$", it probably means strict containment (excluding the possibility of equality); but if it is used with "$\subsetneq$", it probably indicates simple containment (including the possibility of equality). My preference is that "$\subset$" should indicate simple containment (with possible equality), and that strict containment (excluding the possibility of equality) should be indicated by "$\subsetneq$".